# Navigate Sublime Text sidebar within QWERTY keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I always want to discard my mouse and function keys. In Sublime Text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> can focus the sidebar, and using Emacs-like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> can navigate vertically. However when I try to list the files under a folder, I have to use  <kbd>Right</kbd> key to do that. Does anyone know the keybinding for that in the QWERTY layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do that, side bar is completely un customizable besides the visual tweaks.

There is [an open feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/19475-side-bar-api/) for sidebar API, I can't quite understand why this for so long requested feature is still not implemented, at least some basic functionality, but we'll have to wait to get our hands on this part of the editor.

Another thing that is ridiculous for keyboard freaks like us is that on Mac you can't open the context menu on any of the files or folders in the sidebar as you don't have the key like on windows/linux and there's no tweaks for that too.